# Deleting First DropDownList item rather than Selected Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to delete a row in an SQL Server database table using a DropDownList in ASP.net.

I am trying to select an ID from the DropDownList, and delete that row in my table.

However, instead, the first item in the list is being deleted

Below is my database table:

```
[ID]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Order] INT           NOT NULL,
[Desc]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL
```

And here is my C#:

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from tblImages where ID='" + ddlDeleteHomeSlideImage.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ResultLabel.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
}
```

Here is my ASPX:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        <strong>Image to delete: </strong>
                        <br />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDeleteHomeSlideImage" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteHomeSlideImage" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnDeleteHomeSlideImage_Click" />
                        <asp:Label ID="ResultLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You are using the selectedItem and not the first item.

Comment: Do you want to delete the first one or you want to delete the selected one? Also, you should use SqlParameters and NEVER append values like you did

Comment: @Marco When I choose a different item (i.e. not the first item), it still deletes the first item

Comment: @Nobody I'm trying to delete the selected item, but it is deleting the first one

Comment: what happens when you try to delete other than first item in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Can you post your aspx page code?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. As it stands curently it is almost incomprehensible. Please add the markup for the Dropdownlist too. Which value is `SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: Have you tried with SelectedValue?

Comment: @Nobody Yes, I have and it still deletes the first item. Also, aspx has been posted above

Comment: Can post the code you use to fill the data in the drop down list?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: And seriously those columns names are dreadful. You should not use reserved words for columns names. It is incredibly confusing and difficulte to work with. If you use identity as your primary key it should have an attribute ID. So something like ImageID that will remain that same name in every single table, not change its name for other tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Sweg solution, with SQL Parameters to avoid SQL Injection

```
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from tblImages where ID= @id", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", ddlDeleteHomeSlideImage.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what the issue was. I removed the single-quotation marks in the SQL Command and it works fine now.

Here is the code which works:

```
  con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from tblImages where ID=" + ddlDeleteHomeSlideImage.SelectedItem.ToString(), con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: This is still a dangerous solution!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDeleteHomeSlideImage" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

Your DropDownList will be updated if you change the selected Item. Now your DropDownList will be updated in the server side.

Comment: I've just tried this, but it just keep's refreshing the page & the selected item returns to the first item in the DropDown

Comment: What do you have in the Page_Load method?

Comment: This is not what autopostback does. Autopostback posts everytime an element is selected.
It does not fix the issue in any way and breaks the logic @Sweg